PC freezes for a second when clicking on volume/wifi/battery menu windows 11
When I click on the Sound, Wi-Fi and Battery menu (bottom right of the screen) the screen freezes for a second or two the first time I log into Windows or when it is clicked for the first time in a while and after that it does not freeze however many times I click it.
I have windows 11(version 10.0.22631 Build 22631) on my new laptop, HP Victus 16-r0003nu.
These are I think the same cases
Case1 Case2 but without answers in them.
